# multiple system call from node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was trying to call multiple system call from node js

my code snippet :

```
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;                        
function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }                                               
exec("rfkill block bluetooth ; rfkill unblock bluetooth ; hciconfig hci0 down ; hciconfig hci0 up", puts);
console.log('BLE intialization DONE');
```

But those had no effect.if I implement them one by one in (ie. editing file and then put command one after another and then execute ) it was working. Let me know if anyone can suggest and workaround for this.

EDIT : or is there any example where multiple system call can be done one after another

Answer (score 1):

Node 12 has a [synchronous child process execution interface](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_synchronous_process_creation) for scripting purposes:

> Synchronous Process Creation
>
> These methods are synchronous, meaning they WILL block the event loop, pausing execution of your code until the spawned process exits.
>
> Blocking calls like these are mostly useful for simplifying general purpose scripting tasks and for simplifying the loading/processing of application configuration at startup.

StrongLoop has an introduction to [using it for scripting](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/whats-new-in-node-js-v0-12-execsync-a-synchronous-api-for-child-processes/):

```
var history = child_process.execSync('git log', { encoding: 'utf8' });
process.stdout.write(history);
```

In your case, you should check for errors in each command (assuming you care about them) and respond appropriately:

```
var shellCommands = ['rfkill block bluetooth', 'rfkill unblock bluetooth', 'hciconfig hci0 down', 'hciconfig hci0 up'];
shellCommands.forEach(function(command) {
    var execResponse = child_process.execSync(command, { encoding: 'utf8' });
    // if execResponse is non-zero, an error will be thrown here
    // if you want to continue, you should handle it with try/catch
    process.stdout.write(history);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your code isn't working.  I have lots of commands strung together in a single exec just like you are doing in multiple places in code I'm working on and it works just fine.  I think what you may be seeing is that your output statement `console.log('BLE initialization DONE')` is fooling you into thinking your exec is done when it's not at all.  The exec is asynchronous the way you are using it so you aren't going to wait until it's done before your output message is shown.

Instead, try this:

```
var sCommand = "rfkill block bluetooth ; rfkill unblock bluetooth ; hciconfig hci0 down ; hciconfig hci0 up";

exec(sCommand, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log("error: ", error);
    console.log("stdout: ", stdout);
    console.log("stderr: ", stderr);

    console.log('BLE initialization DONE');
    puts(error, stdout, stderr);
    });
```